# How to transfer a file from Windows XP to a virtual machine inside vSphere 5.5?

Tags: vsphere, pscp

I have a file on my desktop that I need to put onto one of the virtual machines, however when I search for solutions on how to do this many say to download third party software to do it, or to use drag and drop through vSphere. The issue is I am on a restricted network and can't install additional software, and also don't have the drag an drop functionality in vSphere.

I have seen it done in the past using the command line and the IP address of the machine I want to send it to, along with the username and password, however I can't remember the syntax. Can anyone provide instruction on what to type into the terminal to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the `Copy-VMGuestFile` cmdlet a look from PowerCLI? 
http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI651/html/Copy-VMGuestFile.html

If you're not a fan of PowerShell, there's a couple SDK options you could use with the vSphere Web Services API. Specifically, you're looking for the GuestFileManager object and the InitiateFileTransferToGuest method: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-5-5/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.vm.guest.FileManager.html